# how can create extention in xcode 6 beta?

Tags: ios, ios8, xcode6, ios-app-extension

I downloaded Xcode 6 beta and was interested in Extension programming for iOS 8. However, I have been unable to locate the extensions in my project templates when creating a new project in Xcode

now i try to create extention but after create how can run and how can it's work i din't understand.

i read this [link](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/ExtensionOverview.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014214-CH2-SW2) but didn't understand.

can any one help me about apple new feture extention.

Answer (score 0):

Extensions are additional targets in an existing iOS project. Open or create an iOS Project. Add a new target: File:Target select Application Extension.

Comment: how can launch after adding Extension in project?